# Apple wallet discount Personalized coupon dynamic serial number/barcode

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, wallet, passkit

I working on apple "passkit" framework. 
I already build lolipop coupon as it saying in [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1). 
 - Created Certificate (Apple Dev Website)
i already compiled .pkpass.

Now i have to build coupon with dynamic barcode/serial number (Personalized). I'm not able to figure out how can i inject my dynamic code in json because, whenever i do any changes in pass.json i have to compile `./signpass -p myfolder.pass` to see changes.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamic code in pass.json, you need to create a Web API for pass update, you may refer to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1). For more easy to develop or maintenance, **you may update pass in every user request** (just using http action result return a .pkpass file and status code 200)

I hope the following URL is helpful for you to understand how apple pass work:

```
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1
https://www.raywenderlich.com/20785/beginning-passbook-in-ios-6-part-22
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_passkit
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much let go throw the links ...look like you gave me that what i was looking.

Comment: i just posted new question on jpasskit if you could help me or if you used any other library if you can guide me. Thanks